# PyQt: error with converting to Qt Designer UI file to Python module

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, pyuic

When I try to convert a `ui` file to `py` using this command:

```
pyuic4 -o test.ui test.py
```

it gives this error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There must be a conflict with your python and pyqt system installation. For example, you installed a Python 3.4 (x64) and installed the PyQt (x86) or vice versa. Can you give more details about the version you are using ?

Comment: how can i show u the version ?

Comment: open `cmd.exe` write `python` then `import platform` then `platform.platform()` and copy the output. Also how did you install PyQt ? did you use binaries or pip ?

Comment: 'Windows-8-6.2.9200' heres the platform
also i installed it from a exe that i found

Comment: we will continue in a chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135620/pyqt4-error-with-transferring-to-python-file-from-ui

Comment: i cant i must have 20 rep to talk there :/

Comment: what you can do is go to Install Uninstall programs in Widows and read the version of Python if it is (x64) or (x86), do the same with PyQt.

Comment: so i downloaded the python here : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-340/ and i downloaded the MSI x86 ... and the pyqt is x64 from what i remember ... that can cause the problem ?

Comment: yes this is the problem, you have to match the python installed version which is x86 in your case. So uninstall pyqt x64 and install the pyqt binaries x86. This should work.

Comment: i cant find a x86 pyqt download and the python is only x86... do u know how can i download a x64 python ?

Comment: here is a link to pyqt4 x86 for python 3.4 x86 : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.5.0-x32.exe/download

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD!!!!! thanks so much for helping me dude... i didnt know x86 is 32 bit ... so weird... why would they do that ? anyway thanks for taking your time and helping me .:) do u have a guide on how to work with the designer ?

Comment: No I am not :) but I am glad it helped. I don't work with the designer sorry, I write most of my UI with code. I will make an answer so it can help other users.

Answer (score 0):

This error is frequent and basically it says that to have Python and PyQt working correctly, system versions need to match.

e.g: if you have Python 3.4 **(x86)** you will need PyQt **(x86)**

Windows binaries for **PyQt4/PyQt5** **x86/x64** can be found in the SourceForge repository : https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/